# Sqlite - get different results from row "album" - python

Tags: python, sqlite

**The problem**

When I search my sqlite database for a list of albums with the name "Batman" it gives me a list of tracks with "Batman" instead.

I have a Table called "tracks" with the columns: `title`, `album`, `comment`, `genre`, `artist`, `composer`, `year`

Here is the code:

```
import sqlite3

connecttosql = sqlite3.connect('musicdatabase.db')

connectioncursor = connecttosql.cursor()

def playmusic(name):
        #connectioncursor.execute("SELECT title, composer, album, year FROM tracks WHERE album LIKE ?", ('%' +name+ '%',) ) #This is for more detail
        connectioncursor.execute("SELECT album FROM tracks WHERE album LIKE ?", ('%' +name+ '%',) ) #This is for just the album name
        rows = connectioncursor.fetchmany(10)
        print(rows)
        print("Finish")
        input()
        connecttosql.commit()
        connecttosql.close()

try:
    s=raw_input("name: ")
    playmusic(s)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    print("Error")
```

Here are the results:

```
[(u'Batman Return of the Joker',), (u'Batman Return of the Joker',), (u'Batman Return of the Joker',), (u'Batman Return of the Joker',), (u'Batman Return of the Joker',), (u'Batman Return of the Joker',), (u'Batman Return of the Joker',), (u'Batman Return of the Joker',), (u'Batman Return of the Joker',), (u'Batman Return of the Joker',)]
```

Here is what I would like:

```
[(u'Batman Return of the Joker',), (u'1989 Batman on Nes',), (u'Batman on Psx',), (u'Other Batman game',)]
```

I assume its a search by column but I am not sure of where to do that. If anyone has any ideas let me know. I will keep researching as well.

Thank you for your time,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out my own answer! You need to use the `DISTINCT` statement to return unqie values:

`connectioncursor.execute("SELECT DISTINCT album FROM tracks WHERE album LIKE ?", ('%' +name+ '%',) )`

https://www.dofactory.com/sql/select-distinct